# Oracle: Binary integer type

Tags: oracle

I want to basically have an "id" type in Oracle.

An example which would satisfy my needs would be a 32/64 bit integer where `NULL` is represented as `-INT_MIN`.

I don't need this to be variable length (like `NUMBER`). I considered using `RAW` but I don't believe there is an implicit conversion from `RAW` to integers.

It seems an option is `BINARY_DOUBLE`. Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of your entire requirement, but yes it appears you're correct:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i16209

Answer (score 3):

Use `NUMBER(10, 0)`, which is equivalent to `NUMBER(10)`. `BINARY_DOUBLE` is a floating-point representation, not an integer. I figure, don't second-guess the database, unless you have a specific reason to do so. You may be talking yourself out of behind the scenes data optimizations that the CBO can do (though I don't know if there are any). You say you want an integer, so use an integer.

And why would you want to represent NULL as -INT_MIN? Represent NULL as NULL.